# Converges or diverges $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was trying to find if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}$converges or diverges. First, I tried ratio test and got the limit as 1. I tried Limit Comparison Test's and I only got 0's and $\infty$'s. Then I tried using $n\geq \ln n$ for Direct Comparison Tests, but I could not find a result. Can you help me to see what am I missing?

Comment: Hint:  compare it to $\sum \frac 1{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: I will say that my series is smaller than this and since this one diverges, mine will also diverge, right?

Comment: Being smaller than a divergent series tells you nothing, but your series is bigger than the one I gave,

Comment: Ah yeah, I mistyped there, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\sum 1/n^p$ diverges for all $p<1$.

So, the summand is lower bounded by $1/\sqrt{n}$ and is non-negative, so by the comparison test to $\sum 1/\sqrt{n}$ it diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Or in general we can apply the **$ n^{th}$** divergence test stated as
If $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln {n}}{\sqrt{n}}$$ does not exist then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln{n}}{\sqrt{n}} $$
Diverges. This can be a genral test for the testing of series
But in above case the limit exist and equal to $0$ hence this test is not compatible for the series

Comment: But I think that limit exists and is equal to 0, can you check your solution?

Comment: Just observed that by using 'L-Hopital's ' rule the limit is equal to zero, but in my answer above i am talking about the general method for the limit, it can be in conclusive sometimes as in this case.

Comment: @user666150 The limit going to $0$ is a necessary condition. I.e., if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then it must necessarily be the case that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$. However, the converse isn't true: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, but the harmonic series diverges.